# Best way to pad stdin to desired length with NULL

Tags: shell, text-formatting, printf

I have the following requirement. I have an input stream that I need to truncate to a certain fixed length of bytes. I do not know the length of the input stream beforehand. If the stream is less in length than the set length I want to pad it with zero bytes. I tried to use `truncate` but apparently it can only work with files not with stdin.

For example let's assume that our input stream (stdin) is `TEST` and we want to achieve a length of 10 bytes. Then the output stream (stdout) should be `TEST\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`.

To clarify the example is done with small strings, but the result should perform well with large streams (megabytes up to a gigabyte). Also the container I use is currently based on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU `dd`:

```
$ printf %s test | dd iflag=fullblock bs=10 status=none conv=sync count=1 | hexdump -C
00000000  74 65 73 74 00 00 00 00  00 00                    |test......|
0000000a
```

With `zsh`, using its `r`ight padding (and truncating) parameter expansion flag (and the `p` one for escape sequences such as `\0` to be expanded in the padding string):

```
$ string=test
$ printf %s ${(pr[10][\0])string} | hexdump -C
00000000  74 65 73 74 00 00 00 00  00 00                    |test......|
0000000a
```

Though note that it pads to 10 **characters**, not 10 bytes. You can turn the `multibyte` option off to change that (`set +o multibyte`).

```
$ string=tést
$ printf %s ${(pr[10][\0])string} | hexdump -C
00000000  74 c3 a9 73 74 00 00 00  00 00 00                 |t..st......|
0000000b
$ printf %s ${(pr[10][\0])string} | wc -mc
     10      11
```

```
$ set +o multibyte
$ printf %s ${(bpr[10][\0])string} | hexdump -C
00000000  74 c3 a9 73 74 00 00 00  00 00                    |t..st.....|
0000000a
$ printf %s ${(bpr[10][\0])string} | wc -mc
      9      10
```

Those solutions don't scale well to sizes larger than the amount of RAM on the system.

For large sizes, as suggested by @ilkkachu in comments,

```
{ printf %s test; cat /dev/zero; } | head -c 1000000000
```

would be more efficient (`head -c` is not standard but very common and would be a lot more efficient than doing `dd bs=1` which reads and writes one byte at a time).

If the output goes to a file, you could also use resource limits to do the truncating:

```
(
  ulimit -f 1048576 # KiB
  printf %s test
  cat /dev/zero
) > file
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the following solution:

```
echo -n 'TEST' | cat - /dev/zero | dd bs=1 count=10 2>/dev/null | hexdump
```

This works and correctly outputs the following:

```
0000000 4554 5453 0000 0000 0000
000000a
```

So this works for me at least on Linux and I don't care about cross-platform portability. But I feel there might be some command better suited than `dd` to accomplish my goal.

Comment: Just use `perl -e 'print pack "a10", "TEST"'` instead of that monstruosity

Comment: `head -c 10`. Not strictly standard, but widely supported. `dd bs=1` would be slow with longer data. I would probably go with `( echo ...; cat /dev/zero ) | head -c 10` .

Comment: Note that *linux* is just a kernel. There is a very (very) wide range of operating systems that use linux as their kernel with different userland utility implementations.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas true. I should have probably better explained that I want it to run run in my docker container which is currently based on Ubuntu.

Comment: The only non-standard part (beside `hexdump` which you just use to demonstrate the solution) and very unportable though is `echo -n test` which you can easily replace with `printf %s test`

Comment: @ilkkachu I did some quick testing with a ~90MB file that I padded to 100MB head -c performs really well it took 0.24s to finish while dd and bs=1 took 1m23s. So I'm going with your solution. If you add it as an answer I will accept it. 0.24s is fast enough for me at this point the bottle neck is in another place.